# update rows and ignore the one that causes primary key constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with the following constraint definition.

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_TempItemTable_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [A] ASC,
   [B] ASC,
   [D] ASC,
   [D] ASC,
   [E] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I'm attempting to update the column  D with values (about 9000 plus rows);  Due to update values, the constraint error arrives because some value I want to update into D.

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TempItemTable_1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TempItemTable'.

Is there a way for me to write the MS SQL statement that let me update all other rows and ignore the one that will cause this primary key constraint?

Thanks

Comment: can you post the code you've tried that doesn't work?  Basically, you'll need to exclude the rows from your update statement whose PK values already exist

Answer (score 1):

Two options..

1.Create constraint with `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON` and later delete duplicates and set constraint back.

2.Primary key is a combination of columns from A to E,check ,so not sure how checking only  d will help,but with out knowing sample schemas,i can say ,this will exclude all values which are present in table you are going to update

```
update mt
set d=dup.d
from
maintable t
join
ninetythousandtable dup
on dup.d<>t.d
```